# Using a THREE.CanvasTexture with WebGL drawn canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js

I have a Three.js scene which contains a 3D model and is rendered on an existing canvas in my HTML.
I want to pass the texture of this currently rendering canvas to a new canvas in order to use the `THREE.CanvasTexture` in a `RawShaderMaterial`.

```
// 3D Scene Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("#c");
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
(...)
```

```
// Use 3D Scene canvas as texture - not rendering Three.js canvas
let cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
let canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(ctx.canvas);
canvasTexture.needsUpdate = true;
   // use canvasTexture
```

I then want to use this actively rendering canvasTexture as an `uTexture` for a `RawShaderMaterial` which will process this canvas into particles eventually.

As for now, I can render and process the context canvas only if I use `ctx.fillRect()` to draw rectangles or other basic shapes using HTML Canvas, not Three.js rendering.

```
// Use canvas as texture - working with HTML canvas
let cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
ctx.fillRect(20, 10, 150, 100);
let canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(ctx.canvas);
canvasTexture.needsUpdate = true;
   // use canvasTexture
```

I would like to know how I can use an animating 3D canvas as a `THREE.CanvasTexture`.

Comment: If you want to use the data of your first canvas as a texture for a shader, why don't you render into a render target? This is the usual workflow if you need a render pass for further use in a different shader.

Comment: @Mugen87 Completely forgot about render target, it surely was what I needed and I've achieved what I wanted. Thanks so much.